# Assistance refining search results from if loop?

Tags: python, dirname

I am looking for a little assistance to get the desired output from my loop.

I am trying to compile a list of paths leading up to any folder named 'published'. It nearly works but I'd appreciate if someone could show me a way to stop the loop from spitting out any directories that are children of 'published'.

```
import os

file = open('published_directories_list.txt', 'w');
top = "T:\PROJECTS";

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        myPath = os.path.join(root, name);

        if 'published' in myPath:
            print (myPath);
            file.write(myPath + '\n');
        else:
            print (myPath + ' - no published directory!');

file.close();

print('DONE!');
```

Comment: As an aside, `'published' in myPath` will also give True for `mypath="/sadly/unpublished"`, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that `os.walk` iterates over every directory under `top`. So, if you have a directory structure like:

```
top
  |
  - published
  |  |
  |  - something
  |
  - other
```

at some point in your loop your line:

```
myPath = os.path.join(root, name)
```

will be joining a root of `/top/published` and a name of `something`. Obviously, then, when you check `if "published" is in myPath` it will be. Even though you're looking at a sub-directory of `published`, you're still seeing the name "published" in your path.

An easy way to fix this issue would be to check, if `myPath` ends in "published" (using the [endswith](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) string method) instead of checking if it simply contains it. You could modify your `if` statement to read:

```
if myPath.endswith('/published')
```

Note that I included a backslash at the start of what we're checking for. This should fix DSM's point that we don't want to match "unpublished" as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import os
>>> folder = 'MUI'
>>> for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\windows'):
    for dir_ in dirs:
        if folder.lower() == dir_.lower():
            print os.path.join(root, folder)
            dirs.remove(dir_)


C:\windows\MUI
C:\windows\AppPatch\MUI
C:\windows\Help\MUI
C:\windows\Help\Tours\htmlTour\MUI
C:\windows\Help\Tours\mmTour\MUI
C:\windows\Help\Tours\WindowsMediaPlayer\MUI
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\MUI
C:\windows\pchealth\MUI
C:\windows\Resources\Themes\Luna\MUI
C:\windows\Resources\Themes\Luna\Shell\Homestead\MUI
C:\windows\Resources\Themes\Luna\Shell\Metallic\MUI
C:\windows\Resources\Themes\Luna\Shell\NormalColor\MUI
C:\windows\srchasst\MUI
C:\windows\system32\MUI
C:\windows\system32\oobe\MUI
C:\windows\system32\wbem\MUI
C:\windows\Web\MUI
```

Yes, you can touch the `dirs` while iterating (so children won't be browsed here) !!

I used comparisons in lower case because Windows doesn't care about the case, but it displays it. On Unix-like systems a comparison like `if folder in dirs` without the loop would be the good way.